# MS SQL Server 2012: How to configure more than one instance accessible via TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, networking, sql-server-2012, network-protocols

During installation of SQL Server 2012 Express the installation interface said that there
could be at most one Default instance, and that the default instance can be accessed on
the default TCP/IP port 1433.

However, it strikes when more than one instance is created, it must be possible somehow
to configure these to use TCP/IP and run them on some other nondefault TCP/IP ports.
How can I achieve this network configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure what port number an instance listens to using the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool. Even if you change the default port number, 1433, you can still only have one default instance, MSSQLSERVER. You can however install additional instances using unique instance names. You connect to those instances using a server\instance naming convention.

Comment: Not sure why. I've just connected to the default instance but when I run "netstat /a" I don't see the server on that port. My understanding is that the nondefault instances don't use TCP/IP as the protocol, but correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No instances have to use TCP, default or otherwise. You can turn of the TCP endpoint if you don't want to accept remote connections. I think SQL Express has TCP turned off by default. You configure that in the configuration manager as well.